# nested loop with file1.csv and file2.csv in jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, nested-loops

I am using Apache JMeter and I need to run function call in 2 nested loops driven by csv datafiles. There is similar Q&A at [How to implement nested loop in jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993754/how-to-implement-nested-loop-in-jmeter) but it's not based on datafiles.

I have 2 files:

**long.csv**:

```
1
2
3
...
100.000
```

and **short.csv**:

```
a
b
c
```

I need to run nested loop test with data from those files

```
foreach x from long.csv
  foreach y from short.cvs
    call(x,y)
```

and I want the calls look like this:

```
call(1,a)
call(1,b)
call(1,c)
call(2,a)
call(2,b)
call(2,c)
call(3,a)
call(3,b)
call(3,c)
...
call(100000,a)
call(100000,b)
call(100000,c)
```

The calls may be reordered, but I need unique call on every combination of inputs.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for detailed steps, please check here.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-looping-2-csv-files/

---

I tried & it seems to work - Please check below snapshot for details.

CSV Data set Config 1 reads a csv file - the var ref name is 'vara'.
it has 10 rows , 1-10

CSV Data set Config 2 reads another csv file , contains 3 rows a, b c - and the var ref name is 'varb'. 'Allow ReCycle on EOF?' is set to True.

Thread Loop Count is for CSV Data set Config 1 
Inner Loop Controller's loop count is for CSV Data set Config 2

[image]

Comment: Got similar solution by myself with the little help of burning the midnight oil yesterday. I must set Loop Counter's loop count to Config2 amount of lines (3) and it works nice even with multiple threads.

Comment: BTW: what is the configuration of Debug sampler there? I was not able to reproduce the beauty of your output.