# JMeter CSV Looping two files

Tags: csv, jmeter

I'm trying to make a test plan for our new application, and we need to make requests as:

hhtp://appName/stations/${idStation}/variables/${idVariable}

For a full stress plan we want all possibilities, so we have defined two csvs one with stations ids and another one with variables ids:

```
idStations.csv
AA
BB
CC
DD
EE
FF

idVariables.csv
1
2
3
```

We already now how to combine csv in the same plan to have this combinations:

AA  1
BB  2
CC  3
DD  1
EE  2
FF  3

But what we really want is to do this combinations:

AA 1
AA 2
AA 3
BB 1 
BB 2
BB 3
CC 1
CC 2
CC 3
DD 1
DD 2
DD 3
EE 1
EE 2
EE 3
FF 1
FF 2
FF 3

How can we do this in a clean way? thanks is advance!

Comment: I've found a possible solution on the first answer of this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655918/nested-loop-with-file1-csv-and-file2-csv-in-jmeter

Comment: why not merge it in single file beforehand?

Comment: Merging you do not have flexibility, and the amount of combinations in a real test plan is too much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for detailed steps, please check here.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-looping-2-csv-files/

---

The answer here will work for your scenario as well.

[nested loop with file1.csv and file2.csv in jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655918/nested-loop-with-file1-csv-and-file2-csv-in-jmeter)

I get the output as given below.

[image]

**Settings**

- Thread Group is set to run forever
- "CSV Data Set Config FileA" is set to

  TRUE for 'Stop Thread on EOF?' 
     FALSE for 'Recycle on EOF'
- Loop Controller Count is equal to the no of items in the FileB.  You can parameterize it.
- "CSV Data Set Config FileB" is set to

  FALSE for 'Stop Thread on EOF?' 
    TRUE for 'Recycle on EOF'