# Jmeter; control foreach nested

Tags: foreach, jmeter

Is it possible to put 2 foreach control nested in Jmeter?

I would like to do something like that:

```
Set variables 1 (with 5 variables)
Foreach (from 1 to 5)
   Set variables 2 (with 3 variables)
   Foreach (from 1 to 3)
        HTTP petition, with 2 parameters (1 from setvariables 1 and another from setvariables2)
```

The result I expect is 15 HTTP petitions.

The result that I have got now is only 3 HTTP petitios (only with the first value o Setvariable 1).

Comment: Case with nested Loop Controllers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12997180/993246.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

I have variables like

```
A_1 = a
A_2 = b
A_3 = c
A_4 = d
A_5 = e
```

&

```
B_1 = 1
B_2 = 2
B_3 = 3
B_4 = 4
B_5 = 5
```

The outer `for loop` for Variable A & inner loop is for B. 
For each 'A', i get all B executed as given below.

[image]

---

It is possible to do with `CSV Data Set Config` as well.

Check this in detail in my blog here.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-looping-2-csv-files/