# JMeter simplistic nested loop

Tags: jmeter

I am tryig to implement a simple nested loop in JMeter 3.2.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993754/how-to-implement-nested-loop-in-jmeter) did not work for me.

You can find my test plan [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zopnp6ix471uchz/tmp.jmx?dl=0), I've hosted it on my Dropbox. I tried to keep things **really** simple. If you don't want to download the test plan, here's what I do :

- **Thread Group**

  - View result tree
  - Loop controller (*forever*)

    - Counter (*Start:0, Increment:1, Maximum:10,Reference Name:loopX, track counter independently for each user: checked*)
    - Loop controller (*forever*)

      - Counter (*Start:0, Increment:1, Maximum:5,Reference Name:loopY, track counter independently for each user: checked*)
      - Debug Sampler

Now when I take a look at the loops in the `Response data` tab from the Debug Sampler, I only see `loopY` varying, from 0 to 5. Obviously I am expecting `loopX` to vary too, from 0 to 10.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first loop controller won't ever "loop" as you have nested Loop Controller in "forever" mode. `loopX` counter will start incrementing only when second loop controller will exit the loop and with your current configuration it is not achievable.

If you need to increment 2 counters separately you can take a look into [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function or add `loopX` counter to the second loop controller. See [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really a dumb mistake. Thank you the explanation and the different links. I really appreciate all your work around Jmeter.